# Rails ApplicationLayout Gives Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, routes

when i generate a scaffold, my app doesn't render on localhost:3000 it says

```
Showing C:/Users/haruntuncay/deneme/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:".
```

When i delete

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' =>true %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

these 3 lines from application.html.erb, it solves the problem.But then my Delete Route is not working.Even if i add "method: :delete" to it.I know rails use javascript for handling deletes.But if i dont delete js in my layout, my app doesn't render anything. What should i do?

Comment: can you show us the error ?

Comment: Showing C:/Users/haruntuncay/deneme/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised" TypeError: object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: which line of the above is exactly line 5 ? and can you include the full error with the stack trace(preferably without library stack trace) in the question ?

Comment: it got solved when i updated the coffe script gem version to 1.8.0. ^^ thx for helping.

Comment: you're welcome, please post an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

It got sovled when i changed my coffee script to 1.8.0 from 1.10.0.
get coffee script 1.8.0" and then "bundle update coffee script source".